# NVIDIA GPU not showing up in lspci

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver, additional-drivers

The Dedicated GPU of my Laptop, an GTX 970M by NVIDIA is not showing up in lspci. I have installed the lastest nvidia-361 drivers and im running Ubuntu 16.04 using the 4.6 Kernel. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by adding a graphics driver ppa, and installing the lastest nvidia-367 drivers.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```

Comment: Even if this is an old answer, it is still relevant today (for Ubuntu 21.04) -- just might need to use a different driver version (a guide is available on the [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)).

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo lshw` instead. Sorry for the extremely short answer but choices being what they are in this case.....

Comment: I already fixed this by installing the nvidia-367 drivers from ppa which fixed this issue.

Comment: @spyfly So answer it with your solution. Perhaps someone will prefer your approach