# lspci doesn't show graphics card

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

My current setup is 0C2KJT motherboard with a corsair cx650m PSU, and a gtx 1070 card. I have tested the graphics card on another computer and it works. I don't think it's power requirements, as it's simply enough power & I can see the graphics card power on. So hopefully I've ruled out any 'superuser' questions.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. There is no output for `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` and the output of `sudo lshw -C video` only points to the "Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller".

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Dell Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

[This questions answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804677/nvidia-gpu-not-showing-up-in-lspci) states that the fix is simply to directly install the driver. So for that I simply

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

Still no results in `lscpi`.

What's the next step I could do for troubleshooting? Or should I assume that the PCI slot is dead?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: If a device is not seen in `lspci` it is not a matter of drivers.

Comment: Edited. So if it's not a matter of drivers is there any next step I can take that involves ubuntu?

Comment: This must be a hardware issue. There are no "steps" until you see the card there.

Comment: power down the box and unplug it then remove the nvidia board and then put it back in ...  sometime its not seated snug enough

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Reseated and there is no listing. Guess my PCIex16 slot is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graphics card isn't listed in `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` & I've done necessary hardware troubleshooting. Likely case is that the PCI slot isn't functional.